# Extract a whole word containing a specific character or a chain of character

Tags: r, regex

i would like to extract a chain of character from a "sentence". I tried with `str_extract` but i'm not able to find the good reg exp. Although, i'd like to know if there is another way to do this.

Here is some example of sentences i work with:

```
sentence <- 
c("PT AT FB AT MQ LGMS PF PRVNCL 1CT 200G *",
"PT AT FB AT MQ SC CLS PF BBQ 1CT 200G *",
"PT AT FB AT MQ SC CLS PF BSQ 1CT 200G *",
"AT FB AT MQ SC CLS PF TX MX 1CT 200G * I",
"PR FCLNTS PT HNZ LGMS MF BSLC 2CT 490G *",
"FCLNTS PT HNZ LGMS MF ARRBT 2CT 490G * I",
"FCLNTS PT HNZ PST MF PST RG 2CT 490G * I",
"LGMS MF PVRNS GRLLS & FRMG IT 2CT 490G *")
```

I need to extract every `"numG"`, it means every `200G`, `490G`,... etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll have only one `"numG"` in each `sentence` you can use `sub`

```
sub(".*?(\\d+G).*", "\\1", sentence)
#[1] "200G" "200G" "200G" "200G" "490G" "490G" "490G" "490G"
```

If they are going to be multiple, you can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_extract_all(sentence, "\\d+G")
```

Or

```
regmatches(sentence, gregexpr("\\d+G", sentence))
```

Comment: thank you, the first one is exactly what i'm looking for